# Change Picker's content dynamically

Tags: swiftui

I want to change Picker's content dynamically.
But I think you cannot pass Binding property into ForEach.

```
@Binding var options: [String]
@Binding var selectedIndex: Int

var body: some View {
    Picker(selection: self.$selectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0..<self.$options.count) { // error: Cannot assign to property: 'count' is a get-only property
            Text(self.options[$0])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct TestPickerView: View {
    @Binding var options: [String]
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$selectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(Array(self.options.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, item in
                Text(item).tag(index)
            }
        }.id(options)     // << important !!
    }
}
```

Note: a Picker have to be explicitly depend on options to be updated/rebuilt when number of options changed, this is what `id` is needed for.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful support.  
  
Another problem occured.  
When I define options as [Int] and select Picker, the Picker pass element itself into selectedIndex even though set .tag(index)